# How to save items to cart using localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a table like this:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th> Book Title </th>
        <th> Author </th>
        <th> Book </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id= Book_Title>Gone </td>
        <td id= Author>Micheal Grant</td>
        <td><button id="AddToCart" onclick="addToLocalStorage()">Add To Cart</button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id= Book_Title>The Knife of never letting go</td>
        <td id= Author>Ryan Howard</td>
        <td><button id="AddToCart" onclick="addToLocalStorage()">Add To Cart</button> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My goal is to have, on button click for the data of a specific row to be saved to local storage. However, because the id's are the same for each row only the first instance of the id will save. I was wondering how I could use jquery closest() to fix my problem. Or even if there is any other solution to my problem.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is **invalid HTML**. You should fix that before going further.

Comment: Your id values all need to be unique. You should wrap your id values in double quotes. Example: id="Book_Title"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save the data contained in your table's row... Like the book title and author, I suggest you to use some [`objects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) contained in an [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Then you'll have to [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) that prior to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

When you'll want to retreive the stored data, you'll have to [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it back to an array of objects.

**Sadly**, SO snippets do not like the use of localStorage... So my working demo is on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WJyxMO?editors=1011).

Here's the relevant code:

```
// The "add to cart" handler.
$("table").on("click", ".AddToCart", function(e){

  // Get previous storage, if any.
  var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
  if(storage==null){
    storage = [];
  }

  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var title = row.find("td").eq(0).text().trim();
  var author = row.find("td").eq(1).text().trim();

  // Create an object to store.
  var data = {author:author,title:title};
  storage.push(data);

  // Store it.
  localStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(storage));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of IDs, and attach the listener using Javascript instead of inline attributes (which is as bad as `eval`). No need for jQuery. For example:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.className !== 'AddToCart') return;
  // e.target refers to the clicked button:
  const [bookTd, authorTd] = [...e.target.closest('tr').children];
  addToLocalStorage({ title: bookTd.textContent, author: authorTd.textContent });
});

function addToLocalStorage(obj) {
  console.log('adding ' + obj);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Book Title </th>
      <th> Author </th>
      <th> Book </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Book_Title">Gone </td>
      <td class="Author">Micheal Grant</td>
      <td><button class="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Book_Title">The Knife of never letting go</td>
      <td class="Author">Ryan Howard</td>
      <td><button class="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My guess is the OP would prefer to have the book title and author saved... Not just squarely the row HTML. A result like `{author:"Michael Grant",title:"Gone"}` certainly is closer to the objective...

Comment: Probably something like that, but with no reference to what `addToLocalStorage` actually does or what it needs, I just showed an example of passing the whole `tr`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry for the lack of clarity, would be able to show me something that results in something closer to {author:"Michael Grant",title:"Gone"},

Comment: @googleplex Oh, didn't realize you hadn't written any of the addToLocalStorage function. Just select the `tr'`s children and get the `textContent` of the first and second one