# How to use localStorage in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I try to make a script so it sees which dropdown option I selected but now I want to add `localStorage` to it so it remembers when I leave the page

I made now this code but it doesn't seem to work properly, could someone please help me ?

```
localStorage.setItem($("#drop"));
var selec = localStorage.getItem($("#drop"));
if (selec == null) {
    console.log($("#drop"))
    $("#hide" + $("#drop")[0].value).show();
    $("#drop").change(function() {
        var end = this.value;
        $('.hide').hide();
        $("#hide" + end).show();
    });
} else {
    $("#hide" + selec.value).show();
}
```

My original code (without `localstorage`)

```
console.log($("#drop"))
$("#hide" + $("#drop")[0].value).show();
$("#drop").change(function() {
    var end = this.value;
    $('.hide').hide();
    $("#hide" + end).show();
});
```

html dropdown menu

```
<select id='drop' class='keuze' style="float:right;">
    <option class='keuze' value='table1' selected>Computer</option>
    <option class='keuze' value='table2'>Monitor</option>
    <option class='keuze' value='table3'>Software</option>
    <option class='keuze' value='table4'>Gebruiker</option>
    <option class='keuze' value='table5'>Randapparatuur</option>
    <option class='keuze' value='table6'>Telefoon</option>
    <option class='keuze' value='table7'>Tablet</option>
    <option class='keuze' value='table8'>Laptop</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: my js file

```
$(function() {
    $('#table1').wrap('<div id="hidetable1"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table2').wrap('<div id="hidetable2"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table3').wrap('<div id="hidetable3"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table4').wrap('<div id="hidetable4"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table5').wrap('<div id="hidetable5"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table6').wrap('<div id="hidetable6"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table7').wrap('<div id="hidetable7"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table8').wrap('<div id="hidetable8"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');

    $('#table1').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "font-family": 'Arial',
        "stateSave": true
    });
    $('#table2').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "stateSave": true
    });
    $('#table3').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "stateSave": true
    });
    $('#table4').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "stateSave": true
    });
    $('#table5').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "stateSave": true
    });
    $('#table6').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "stateSave": true
    });
    $('#table7').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "stateSave": true
    });
    $('#table8').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [12, -1],
            [12, "All"]
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }, {
            "bSearchable": false,
            "aTargets": [-1]
        }],
        "stateSave": true
    });
    var selec = localStorage.getItem('drop') || $("#drop").val();
    $("#hide" + selec).show();

    $("#drop").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('.hide').hide();
        $("#hide" + val).show();
        localStorage.setItem('drop', val);
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: Explain me why it doesn't work in my code than @DaCh

Comment: Why don't you just save the value instead of the whole target?

Comment: You can store objects to the localStorage after stringify them as localStorage can only have string values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save items to cart using localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311972/how-to-save-items-to-cart-using-localstorage)

Comment: @Ende What the answer is on the one i mention. and what the answer given here is

Comment: In [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) «C» stands for complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

localStorage can only contain string values, therefore your attempt to store an entire jQuery object will not work. You also need to update localStorage *after* a choice is made. Try this:

```js
var selec = localStorage.getItem('drop') || $("#drop").val();
$("#hide" + selec).show();
$('#drop').val(selec).change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.hide').hide();
  $("#hide" + val).show();
  localStorage.setItem('drop', val);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9kkujkc8/)

Note that the example has to be in a fiddle as SO Snippets restrict access to localStorage.

Comment: Now it hides all the time

Comment: In that case please edit your question to include the relevant HTML.

Comment: added them to the question

Comment: Thanks. I added a working example for you. Also note that I DRY'd up the `wrap()` logic in the fiddle too

Comment: Alright it works now, Thank you man! Only thing that is a bit strange, when I enter the page for the first time there is no selected option but still I have used `selected` in my first option in the html

Comment: Never mind, it only happened to me, on other devices/computers it works fine

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible, given that an option has to be selected by default. If that's happening to you I'd suggest clearing the `drop` property from your localStorage and running the code again

Comment: Would this remove the property after closing window/tab 
`$(window).unload(function(){
  localStorage.removeItem('drop');
});`

Comment: In theory, yes, although it depends on how the browsers are implementing the (rather unreliable) `beforeunload` event. Also - this seems entirely pointless if you want to store information in localStorage. If you're trying to remove an item for debugging purposes, use the dev tools.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

1. To set

   `localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));`
2. To get

   `var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));`
3. To delete

   `localStorage.removeItem('data');`